# Custom forms inside another form?

Tags: 8

Is there any way to create a custom form in which one of its elements is another custom form using the YAML Form module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, please see [Provide mechanism to build composite and/or base forms](https://www.drupal.org/node/2824714)

Comment: Yes! It's exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you so much! Awesome module!